# Tikz Feynman error in irreducible diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, inline, feynman

I am trying to create some feynman diagrams with tikz. My problem is, that I want to create some simple diagrams like vacuum diagrams in φ^4 theory, which are reducible though, so I don't know where to put the vertices and the nodes. For the simplest two point function of free scalar field diagram for example I use this code:

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b,horizontal=c to d] {
a[particle=$x_1$] -- b[particle=$x_2$],
c[particle=$x_3$] -- d[particle=$x_4$],
};+\feynmandiagram [vertical=a to b,vertical=c to d] {
a[particle=$x_1$] -- b[particle=$x_2$],
c[particle=$x_3$] -- d[particle=$x_4$],
};
```

which just gives

[image: this image]

which apparently isn't what i want,the desired diagram is :

[image]

I think the problem lies on the horizontal command which I don't know if stands for more than one variable, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The second image is missing.

Comment: Having not seen the second image: Try compiling with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`/`xelatex`. The `tikz-feynman` package makes use of Lua for positioning stuff, so you won't always get the best results with `pdflatex`

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I editted so you can see the second picture. I have tried lualatex which merely saves the day, since the visuals get better but i still cant get two parallel lines vertically and two parallel lines horizontally as i wish. Meanwhile when i compile whiti lualatex ,my whole text dissaperas, i guess because its in greek which doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) can only use on `horizontal` directive, and in addition doesn't really know how to handle disconnected diagrams.

The solution in your case is actually pretty simple: just connect the diagrams so that the algorithm can handle everything nicely, but then use `draw=none` so that the lines aren't actually drawn.

Here's an example for your first one:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1em]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  a [particle=$x_1$] -- b [particle=$x_2$],
  c [particle=$x_3$] -- d [particle=$x_4$],
  {[edges={draw=none}]
    a -- c, b -- d,
  },
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you want to fine tune the placement of the lines and their separation, it might be easier to then specify the placement of vertices as shown in the Ti*k*Z-Feynman manual.